# Comparison operator not returning correct value

Tags: javascript

Given two strings, each representing a member of the sides of good or evil, find out which side will win.

Good: Hobbits - 1, Men - 2, Elves - 3, Dwarves - 3, Eagles - 4, Wizards - 10

Evil: Orcs - 1, Men - 2, Wargs - 2, Goblins - 2, Uruk Hai - 3, Trolls - 5, Wizards - 10

I have written a function to figure out which side will win. It works most of the time, but sometimes it behaves weird.

```
function goodVsEvil(good, evil){
 //string to array good and array evil in integers
  var aG = good.split(" ").map(x=>parseInt(x))
  var aE = evil.split(" ").map(x=>parseInt(x))

 //calculate final score good and final score evil
  var fSG = aG[0]*1 + aG[1]*2 + aG[2]*3 + aG[3]*3 + aG[4]*4 + aG[5]*10
  var fSE = aE[0]*1 + aE[1]*2 + aE[2]*2 + aE[3]*2 + aE[4]*3 + aE[5]*5 + aE[5]*10

  console.log('equals: '+ (fSG == fSE))
  console.log('good > evil: '+(fSG > fSE))
  console.log('good < evil: '+(fSG < fSE))
}
```

Some error cases:

```
var result = goodVsEvil('1 0 0 0 1 0', '0 0 0 0 0 1 0')
//output
good: 5
evil: 5
equals: false
good > evil: false
good < evil: true
```

another:

```
good: 10
evil: 10
equals: false
good > evil: false
good < evil: true
```

another:

```
good: 2
evil: 2
equals: false
good > evil: true
good < evil: false
```

Here, it's working fine

```
var result = goodVsEvil('1 1 0 0 0 0', '0 0 0 0 1 0 0')
good: 3
evil: 3
equals: true
good > evil: false
good < evil: false
```

This puzzle is from codewars: https://www.codewars.com/kata/good-vs-evil/train/javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you log `fSG` and `fSE`, you will notice that `fSE` in fact equals `15` in your first example, not `5`.

That is because you have a typo in the line that calculates the value. **You are using `aE[5]` twice instead of `aE[6]`**:

```
var fSE = aE[0]*1 + aE[1]*2 + aE[2]*2 + aE[3]*2 + aE[4]*3 + aE[5]*5 + aE[5]*10
```

This should be

```
var fSE = aE[0]*1 + aE[1]*2 + aE[2]*2 + aE[3]*2 + aE[4]*3 + aE[5]*5 + aE[6]*10
```

---

As a side note, please try to find more comprehensive names for your variables. Scrambled three letter combinations make it really hard to understand the intentions behind the values! :-)